# D3.js bubble cloud circles overlap in force layout even with negative charge and collision detection

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working mainly from Jim Vallandingham's Bubble Chart example and I have all the data linked to the circles and the force layout running normally when I first refresh the page. I want the bubbles to be able to split and group together similar to the code running [here](http://vallandingham.me/bubble_chart/) but after I click on the buttons to move the bubbles they all just overlap on each other. You can see the [live version](https://jsfiddle.net/30e1dga6/) of what I have on JSFiddle. In Vallandingham's he writes that the main collision/bubbles not overlapping effect comes from the charge function:

```
function charge(d) {
  return -Math.pow(d.radius/2, 2.0) / 8;
}
```

I used that in my code but for some reason it's not working the same way and I can't figure out why. I have also tried manual collision detection in different ways but I haven't been able to get it to work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Rina, welcome to stackoverflow, Please update your code and provide a working example (not just code). It will help understand the problem and give a quicker solution.

Comment: I did include a link to the working code but you can see it again here: http://executive-gender-gap.herokuapp.com/

Comment: @RinaSchiller The problem is that that's your page, and nobody here can change it. There are several services (jsfiddle, plunker, codepen etc...) that you can use to create a running version that we can change and test. That way, you'll get help faster.

Comment: Thanks! I put up a JSFiddle version here: https://jsfiddle.net/30e1dga6/